# JobService does not require android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE permission

Tags: android, jobservice

I am getting `does not require android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE permission` error  while scheduling my `JobService` and I already have the bind permissions. Below is my code.

```
JobScheduler jobScheduler = (JobScheduler) getSystemService(JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(MainActivity.this,MyJobService.class);
JobInfo.Builder jobInfo = new JobInfo.Builder(101, componentName).setPeriodic(2000);
jobScheduler.schedule(jobInfo.build())

 <service
  android:name=".MyJobService"
  android:permission="android:permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"
  android:exported="true"/>
```

Error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
>       Scheduled service ComponentInfo{services.acadglid.com.acadgildservices/services.com.es.MyJobService}
>       does not require android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE permission

Comment: Have you tried removing `android:permission="android:permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"` from your `service` in the manifest?

Comment: @Signo  Yes, but getting the same error.

Comment: write `android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"` instead of `android:permission="android:permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"`

Comment: @NazmulHaque whats the difference between both  ?

Comment: I think it will be `.` instead of `:` in permission string.@AkhileshMani

Comment: @NazmulHaque Thanks ! It was a my silly mistake.

Answer (score 73):

To solve this problem:

> Scheduled service ComponentInfo{.........}  does not require
>   android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE permission

add the permission:

```
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"
```

but requires the property:

```
android:exported="..."
```

> [**android:exported**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/receiver-element.html): Whether or not the broadcast receiver can receive messages from sources outside its application — "true" if it can, and
>   "false" if not.

For example:

```
    <service android:name="com.jorgesys.jobscheduler.MyService"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"
        android:exported="true"/>
```

Comment: This worked for me beautifully!

I added the following service into my AndroidManifest.xml file:

``<service
            android:name=".service.BluetoothService"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"
            android:exported="true"/>``

Comment: @Elenasys In the past, my Alarm Notifications fired correctly and with no app crashes.  Then app starting crashing with the same Logcat error message in the question above.  I added the permission you recommended and no more crashes.  What changed with the OS?  Is the permission now a requirement for firing Alarm Notifications?

Comment: This is not working in my case,... I am using job intent service

Answer (score 12):

There's a typo in your `Android Manifest`.

Just change the following line:

```
android:permission="android:permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"
                           ^
                           |
                    This " : " is WRONG!
```

to

```
android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"
```

So just change `:` (colon) in to `.` (dot).