# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Scheduled service android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE permission

Tags: android, android-service

I want to run JobIntentService, but I get this error!

```
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Scheduled service ComponentInfo{MyIntentService} 
does not require android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE permission
```

can anybody help me?

I tried this [JobService does not require android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47325618/jobservice-does-not-require-android-permission-bind-job-service-permission)

but it doesn't help.

```
class MyIntentService : JobIntentService() {

@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
override fun onHandleWork(intent: Intent) {
    val CHANNEL_ID = "my_channel_01"
    val channel = NotificationChannel(
        CHANNEL_ID,
        "Channel human readable title",
        NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
    )

    (getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager).createNotificationChannel(
        channel
    )

    val notification = Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
        .setContentTitle("adf")
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_settings_input_component_24)
        .setBadgeIconType(NotificationCompat.BADGE_ICON_SMALL)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_settings_input_component_24,2)
        .setContentText("ewr").build()

    startForeground(1, notification)
    try {

        for (x in 1..10){
            Thread.sleep(1000)
            Log.d("Nurs", "sleep $x")
        }

    } catch (e: InterruptedException) {
        // Restore interrupt status.
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt()
    }
}

internal fun enqueueWork(context: Context?, work: Intent?) {
    enqueueWork(context!!, MyIntentService::class.java, RSS_JOB_ID, work!!)
}

}
```

in MainActivity I call :

```
   val mIntent =  Intent(this, MyIntentService::class.java);
    mIntent.putExtra("maxCountValue", 1000)
    enqueueWork(this, MyIntentService::class.java,
            Companion.RSS_JOB_ID, mIntent)
```

Comment: I am facing the same problem.. any help? I am using JobIntentService class in my case...while if i try this with JobSchecular it is working

Comment: I don't know, try to see the sample project, which @CommosWare recommended

Comment: I already went throught but in that example JobService is being used and I am using JobIntentService

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"` to your `<service>` element for your `JobService`:

```
<service
  android:name=".WorkService"
  android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" />
```

(from [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/FINAL/JobScheduler/WorkQueue))

Comment: I did but  it doesn't help

Comment: @Nurseyit: You might download the sample project and experiment with it. Or, you could update your question with a [mcve], including whatever error message you have currently (which, if you added that permission, will no longer be the error message that you cited in your question).

Comment: But the error says it does not require permission then why we need to mention same permission

Comment: @androidXP: The error message is stating that the current code does not meet the requirements. I agree, though, that the error message is written poorly.